# Trying to dual boot Ubuntu on Early 2011 MacBook Pro and Ubuntu won't boot from USB, what can I do to troubleshoot booting?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb-drive, mac

I've got as far as partitioning the drive with room for Ubuntu and its bootloader and making a bootable USB, but now I'm stuck. I have rEFInd installed and when I restart, it correctly picks up the bootable USB and I select it. It successfully loads the screen that queries me on if I just want to try Ubuntu or if I want to install it right then. Selecting either of those options results in a blank screen indefinitely (I left it running overnight to no avail). So today, I rebuilt the USB and tried it again with the same results, but I then thought to try the disk on my newer computer. It loads right up from the newer computer. So I've started to wonder...

tl;dr: Is there some reason my older Mac wouldn't accept the current version of Ubuntu (16.04.1) or might there be another issue I'm missing? Does anyone know of other troubleshooting techniques I can use to see what might be going wrong in the booting process?

EDIT: I got a bit further using the 'nomodeset' boot parameter, but that only got far enough to throw the error "no ums support in radeon module"